# STIRNG_SPLIT function not working in SSRS DataSet

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

In SSRS DataSet I am trying to pull data using STRING_SPLIT function.

Please refer to below code:

```
SELECT StudentName 
FROM Student 
WHERE StudentId IN (SELECT VALUE FROM STRING.SPLIT(@StudentId,','))
```

@StudentId is a multi select parameter.

Error message: Invalid object name 'dbo.STRING_SPLIT'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SSRS if your parameter is multi value. It is already considered as an array. You should be able to just do this to select the Student Names where the id is in the parameter list.

```
SELECT StudentName 
FROM Student 
WHERE StudentId IN (@StudentId)
```

You are basically saying from the student ID's I selected in the report parameter find me those peoples names and give me the list.